# Is date variable text possible in Photoshop CC 2019

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, cc-2019

I'm trying to create a date variable for a production template in Photoshop so that it updates to the current date when I save a new version of the document.  It doesn't seem like much but over time it could save a ton of clicking and typing. Any ideas?  I know you can do this in InDesign but unfortunately our studio doesn't spring for that.

Comment: not sure about variable but it'll whole lot easy with script,

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there're no date variables in Photoshop but this can be solved using a simple script and Photoshop Events Manager system which allows to run Actions or Scripts after a particular event was fired in PS.

For instance, in a document I have a bunch of layers and a text layer called `_dateTextItem`:

[image]

And I have this script saved anywhere on a computer as a `.jsx` file: `setDate.jsx`:

```
/**
 * @description this function will change the contents of a text layer _dateTextItem to current date and time
 */
(function(){

    var dateLayer;

    try
    {
        dateLayer = activeDocument.layers.getByName("_dateTextItem");
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // if no _dateTextItem layer found, aborting
        return;
    }

    var newDate = new Date();
    var yyyy = newDate.getFullYear();
    var mm = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var dd = newDate.getDate();
    var hh = newDate.getHours();
    var min = newDate.getMinutes();
    var sec = newDate.getSeconds();
    var milliseconds = newDate.getMilliseconds();

    // the format will be YYYY/MM/DD — HH:Min:Sec, change to your preferred version
    dateLayer.textItem.contents = yyyy + "/" + zeroPad(mm) + "/" + zeroPad(dd) + " — " + zeroPad(hh) + ":" + zeroPad(min) + ":" + zeroPad(sec);

    function zeroPad(value)
    {
        if (String(value).length == 1) return "0" + String(value);
        return value;
    }
})();
```

The script will look for a `_dateTextItem` layer and change it contents to a date. If no layer is found, the script will ignore the document.

Now, in Photoshop `File > Scripts > Script Event Manager...` window..

1. I select an event (`Save Document`);
2. Chose a script (`Browse..` and navigate to my `.jsx` file);
3. Add the listener to the list;
4. And done.

[image]

And now if I save my document, the content of the `_dateTextItem` will change to the date, specified in the script:

[image]